# How can I connect to Salesforce using R

Tags: r

I am trying to connect Rstudio to salesforce database using 'RForcecom' package. When I type in my username, password,loginURL and apiVersion I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: na90.salesforce.comservices
```

I found the following link that explains how to go around this issue
https://akitsche.netlify.com/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/ with package called 'curl'.

As I proceed to get the proxy using ie_get_proxy_for_url command, instead of returning me the actual proxies it gives me NULL.

I am using Mac.

```
##Install necessary packages
install.packages("RForcecom")
library(RForcecom)

##Pick out HTTP Proxy
library('curl')
ie_get_proxy_for_url(target_url)


##Connect the exististing Salesforce account to R
connection.salesforce <- rforcecom.login(username, password loginURL, apiVersion)
```

Comment: I actively maintain the **salesforcer** package which you can try using to connect. There is an outstanding issue regarding connecting through a proxy if needed: https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer/issues/32

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use salesforcer when building a pipe into salesforce (SF). For some reason I could not get it to work (my bad) so I built the pipe from scratch.

This response is a description of how to build a data pipe into Salesforce  Lightning (SF) using the SF REST API using OAuth Authorization Flow.

There are a couple of things to setup first:

- You need an active SF account with username and password

You also need:

- the SF token (SF emails this to you open password change)
- customer key, customer secret
- grant service (something like: /services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password)
- login URL (something like: https://login.salesforce.com )

For the customer key & secret, grant service and login URL: consult your IT department or SF application owner.

I use package `httr`, to send a POST to the login URL as follows:

```
data <- POST(
  loginurl %&% grantservice, # %&%: inline user defined function to concatenate two strings
  body = list(
    client_id = customerkey,
    client_secret = customersecret,
    username = username,
    password = password %&% token
))
```

If all goes well, SF will respond by returning data to you and you can obtain the access token and instance URL from SF. You will need this for your subsequent GETs.

```
# obtain content data
content <- content(data)
access_token <- content$access_token
instance_url <- content$instance_url
id <- content$id
token_type <- content$token_type
```

At this time I am authorised by the SF server (for 15 minutes I believe) I am ready to run queries through GETs.
First, I have to define the request headers which contain the access token. The instance URL becomes the prefix to the query. Note that the query has to be an SOQL query in a format according to SF requirements (consult SF documentation, it is rather specific). `ua` is the `user_agent` (also an httr function).

```
  request_headers <- c("Accept" = "application/json", 
                       "Content-Type" = "application/json",
                       "Authorization" = paste0("Bearer ", access_token))
  resultset <- GET(instance_url %&% query,  
                   add_headers(request_headers), ua)

  response_parsed <- content(resultset, "text", encoding="UTF-8")
```

SF returns data which can be extracted with the `content` function from `httr`. This will give me a JSON object which I can transform into a DF (typically DF with list columns if your query was relational).

```
resultset <- fromJSON(response_parsed, flatten = TRUE)
```

`fromJSON` is a function from the `jsonlight` package. Be prepared to do substantial post-processing on this DF to get the data in the shape you require.

SF does not like that you do things easily so here are two hurdles you need to overcome:

1. The length of the string sent to SF using GET is limited to around 16500 characters. This sounds like a lot but you'd be surprised how easy it is to go over this limit. For instance, my query contains an IN clause with thousands 18 character SF Identifiers. You will need to test for the length of your query and break it up into sub-queries. (I create a list of sub-queries of appropriate length and then `lapply` the function that GETs the records from SF).
2. SF returns a maximum of 2000 records for each GET. If you expect more records to be returned you need to look at 2 data elements returned from SF that will allow you to get the next set of 2000 records: `nextRecordsURL` and `done`. `done` is a flag that tells you if there are more records and `nextRecordsURL` contains the location where to send your next GET to. E.g. you can write a simple for loop that keeps going until `done` equals TRUE. Don't forget to combine the data you retrieve in each loop.

You will have to run multiple queries where you had expected one query to do the job. Alas.

The final hurdle to overcome is that the structure of the data from SF really depends on the query (and in extension on the database schema in SF). A query into a relational table will result in a nested list column in the DF that you get. It is really up to you to work out what is the best way to go as only you know how you structure your queries and the database schema.

A final note. I run this script on an R server on a company server inside the corporate firewall. While this is relatively safe, I made sure I did not hard code the credentials into my R code.
It is best to avoid this; people with access to the server can otherwise read your credentials. My naive approach: I created an rds file with encrypted content (using package `cyphr`) for all credentials. On the server, I only store the encrypted file. I created a function that reads and decrypts the rds file. I make sure that this function is only called inside the POST function call. This ensures that the credentials are only existing in RAM without encryption for the duration of the POST function call (once per session). Amateur level security stuff but better than nothing.